# JSON response from object to array

Tags: json, laravel

My laravel returns json as object, its possible (i guess yes) to make it returns array?
from this:
{"data": []}
to this:
["data": []]
i have tried array_values but it cuts "data":, response()->json() as same as array_values cuts "data":

Comment: `["data": []]` is invalid JSON.

Comment: Can you provide a object example ? Is this for JS usage ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
json_decode($response->json(), true)
```

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert the response from {"data": []} to["data": []], ["data": []] is not valid format. Javascript array does not accept this type of value.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript : You can loop over your object {"data": [], "data": []} if it's what you want (Object.keys)
Or just loop over your object.data if you want access the array. (Array.map)

In other language, it's the same your can access Array "data" and loop by the method you want.